# pydev accessing values of a class from one file to another class in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a project using pydev. This is my first project using pydev. 
My project structure is:

```
myProject(project)
    projFolder(folder)
        userInterface.py
        makeTriangle.py
```

I've a file userInterface.py. This file is used to take input from the user and to show the desired result via a class after doing some operations on the input in another file.

Now I've to pass the value returned from this file to another file named makeTriangle. But I am unable to do that. How can I pass the value returned from one file to another file?

Please let me know if I am doing any thing wrong here. Your response will help me to sharpen my skills.

```
### userInterface.py #########
class userInterface():

    getList = []
    maxList = 4

    def getUserList(self):
        print("*** getting user input ***")
        while len(self.getList) < self.maxList:
            item = input("enter numbers: ")
            self.getList.append(item)
        return self.getList    

    def showUserList(self,passedList):
        print("*** showing user input ***")
        print (passedList)

### makeTriangle.py #########
from userInterface import userInterface 

class makeTriangle():    
   ### how to get the value of getUserList here
```

Answer (score 2):

I would put your initialiaztion of userInterface variable in the **init** method:

```
### userInterface.py #########
class userInterface():
    def __init__(self):
        #do initialization.
        self. getList = []
        self. maxList = 4
```

Then in your other file you can create an instance of userInterface and invoke the methods needed. For instance in the example below the doSomething uses getUserList of userInterface.

```
### makeTriangle.py #########
from userInterface import userInterface 

class makeTriangle():    
    def __init__(self):
        #do any initialization.

    def doSomething():
        ### how to get the value of getUserList here 
        UI = userInterface()
        input = UI.getUserList()
        for num in input:
            #do whatever
```

I strongly recommend you read how classes work in python. Checkout https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you really need to read the docs, but basically any thing that you labled with self.xxxx and any methods you made can be accessed in makeTriange by saying userInterface.xxxxx

so if you need access to the maxList variable, its:

```
userInterface.maxList
```

if you need to use the getuserList() function, its

```
userInterface.getUserList()
```

But like the other poster said, you should be using init(). Right now, you are making CLASS variables. Remember, you usually want to give these attributes to the objects you are making with the class, not the class it self, the init() method will do this for you.

right now, every time you are making a triangle, you are appending to the same list because getList is a CLASS method, but I think you want a new list for each triangle, so you need to make it an INSTANCE method by putting it in init(), which implicitly gets called every time you make an object with the class.

all of this is explained in the docs.